# How to test url when primary key variable is in the middle

Tags: django, testing

I use TestCase to test my django project. And when I want to test the URL for a book's detail I will visit the URL

```
/books/<int:pk>/
```

I will test the url in my test file by

```
self.client.get('/books/', kwargs={'pk':self.book.pk})
```

The PROBLEM is:
If the url of book details lies at

```
/mathbranch/<int:pk>/books/
```

How can I write a test for this url?

Thank you!

Comment: can you try this self.client.get('/mathbranch/{pk}/books/', kwargs={'pk':self.book.pk})
or can you try this self.client.get('/mathbranch/{pk}/books/$', kwargs={'pk':self.book.pk})

Comment: Thanks you for your good hint. I made out that it is just use 'self.client.get('/mathbranch/{0}/books/'.format(self.book.pk))'.  Old python statement, However, I am terrified by django's own way!

Comment: You can write `pk=self.book.pk` instead of `kwargs={'pk':self.book.pk}` in your argument.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps with a regular expression:

```
import re
def test_url_pattern(self):
    expected_url_pattern = r'/mathbranch/\d+/books/'
    the_url_being_tested = '/mathbranch/1092/books/'
    self.assertTrue(re.match(expected_url_pattern, the_url_being_tested))
```